# Render map tiles in node js from GeoTIFF image

Tags: node.js, geotiff

I have an app showing base map as default layer. I need to show an overlay layer to this map from GeoTIFF image, becaue the geotiff images are quite large. I figured out, that rendering map tiles on Node js server might be a solution. So I made request to endpoint like /z/x/y.png and the server would return the map tile rendered from the image or just transparent png if the image is not in the requested area.

Can someone please at least direct me to some way a can do this?